# Set generateBackupPoms To False In Pom

Tags: maven

All our builds add the parameter ''-DgenerateBackupPoms=false'' to the command line while releasing, which I think is kind of stupid and I want to add it to the shared parent *pom.xml*. But I can't figure out which plug-in it is that generates the backup poms.

I searched the [Maven Release Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/), but no luck.

Then I tried the ''versions-maven-plugin'' (that at least has the parameter), but changing it to false does not help:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <generateBackupPoms>false</generateBackupPoms>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The backup poms are still generated. So how do I turn them off?

Comment: How do you call versions-maven-plugin?

Comment: @khmarbaise I don't. As I said, I just tried that because that plug-in at least has the correct parameter.

Comment: try releasing with `mvn -X ...`. Then look for a debug line about your backup pom, you should see which plugin is creating the backup pom. JEEZ. Just realized this is a year and a half old... sorry :)

Answer (score 2):

Simply add it to the `properties` of `pom.xml`:

```
<project>
    <properties>
        <generateBackupPoms>false</generateBackupPoms>
    </properties>
</project>
```